# Get html cross site, display it and get an element value

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I need to get the complete output from an aspx site. When the user leaves I will save what's in some specific elements in cookies. The problem is that the aspx is on a domain I don't have access to. I want the output to behave as in an iframe so links need to be clickable but it won't leave my page.

I think of either AJAX with PHP-proxy or an iframe that I can modify content in.
Is this possible?
If it is possible and it involves server-side code I would like to know if there are any free web hosts that support the full code( for example almost every free web host has safe_mode on for PHP).

EDIT: I want to display this page : [School scheme](http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/%28S%28lv1isca2txx1bu45c3kvic45%29%29/design1.aspx?schoolid=27500&code=82820). The URL doesn't to change, it just sends requests to the server (think via JavaScript). When the user leaves I will see what's in the select box id="TypeDropDownList" and what's in the select box id="ScheduleIDDropDownList".

When the user returns to my page I will print those values to the page via URL like this `"http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/(S(lv1isca2txx1bu45c3kvic45))/design1.aspx?schoolid=27500&code=82820&type=" + type + "&id=" + id + "`

I tried several php proxy scripts on 000webhost before I posted here.
for example this :

```
<?php
ob_start();

function logf($message) {
  $fd = fopen('proxy.log', "a");
  fwrite($fd, $message . "\n");
  fclose($fd);
}

?>
<?
$url = $_REQUEST['url'];
logf($url);
$curl_handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Owen's AJAX Proxy");

$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
$content_type = curl_getinfo($curl_handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
curl_close($curl_handle);
header("Content-Type: $content_type");
echo $content;
ob_flush();
?>
```

But it returns Warning: curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource in /home/a5379897/public_html/ajax-proxy.php on line 16

I tried to contact them about this because they say they have cURL enabled but they haven't responded yet.

I think it would be possible to just display the two select boxes when the user first visit the page. When options is selected it will make an iframe show the right page by passing "http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/(S(lv1isca2txx1bu45c3kvic45))/design1.aspx?schoolid=27500&code=82820&type=" + type + "&id=" + id + " to the src attribute.
The problem with that is that I will need to retrieve the select boxes someway and I will have the same problem.

Comment: There must be a simpler way.  What is your end goal?  What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I concur with Stephen... I've done something similar before, and it's not pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the whole aspx output as a string to manipulate, you can use `file_get_contents(http://yoursite.com/yourpage.aspx);`

For best results, open a stream as the context via http.

```
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents('http://www.example.com/', false, $context);
?>
```

Comment: thanks, I will try that later and tell you if I got it working. First I will need to find a free web host that supports it. If I find one I will of course write which one it is.

Comment: I tried your script in WampServer but when I try to view the aspx page I get this error :
Not Found

The requested URL /MZDesign1.aspx was not found on this server.

Comment: I entered http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/(S(jaz2h3z1eziugm45upgm4y3p))/design1.aspx?schoolid=27500&code=82820&type=3&id={7294F285-A5CB-47D6-B268-E950CA205560} in file_get_contents

Comment: I think I need to change all URLs and see what happens after that

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use PHP as Javascript doesn't doesn't allow cross domain requests. Your PHP code would literally grab the page the client wants, process it (changing link's href to your page with a get variable of the page the original href links to). When they click the link they will be sent to the same page they are on now but the page will grab the new page and return that(processing that page too) and so on.

000webhost are a nice free webhost that allow you to do most of PHP's functions and don't put adverts on your site.

Comment: I have tried 000webhost before I posted here and I was trying to use cURL and unfortunately it didn't work. They also have safe_mode on and I can't use fopen there either.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to greg I could create this script that gets the page.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
// Create a stream
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"GET",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n" .
              "Cookie: foo=bar\r\n"
  )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$host = 'http://www.novasoftware.se/webviewer/(S(bkjwdqntqzife4251x4sdx45))/';
$url = '/design1.aspx?schoolid=27500&code=82820&type=3&id={7294F285-A5CB-47D6-B268-E950CA205560}';
$changetothis='src="'.$host;
// Open the file using the HTTP headers set above
$file = file_get_contents($host.$url, false, $context);
$changed = str_replace('src="', $changetothis,$file);
echo $changed;

?>
</body>
</html>
```